# markov chain computation

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I consider a 2 state Markov chain: $X = \{1,2\}$, transitions are
$M(i,j)$ and the matrix has a unique stationary distribution $\pi$:

$$    \pi(1) = \frac{M(2,1)}{2-M(1,1) - M(2,2)}
    \\
    \pi(2) = \frac{M(1,2)}{2-M(1,1) - M(2,2)}.
$$

I try to compute
$$
\sum_{i,j\in X} \pi(i) (M^k(i,j) -\pi(j)) \mu_i \mu_j
$$
where $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are reals. This is supposed to be 
$$
\pi(1) \pi(2) (\mu_1 - \mu_2)^2 (1-M(1,2) - M(2,1))^k
$$but why?

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the powers of $M$ (see here: [How to compute the powers of $2\times2$ Markov matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015085/how-to-compute-the-powers-of-2-times2-markov-matrices))
shows that the matrix whose $(i,j)^{\rm th}$ entry is $\pi(i)(M^k(i,j)-\pi(j))$
can be written  $$A:=\underbrace{\pi(1)\pi(2)(1-M(1,2)-M(2,1))^k}_{\rm scalar}\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}.$$

The expression you want is 
\begin{eqnarray*} \mu^T A \mu &=&\pi(1)\pi(2)(1-M(1,2)-M(2,1))^k \pmatrix{\mu_1&\mu_2}\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}\pmatrix{\mu_1\\ \mu_2}\\
&=&\pi(1)\pi(2)(1-M(1,2)-M(2,1))^k (\mu_1-\mu_2)^2.
\end{eqnarray*}