# How to compute the powers of $2\times2$ Markov matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions

Consider a Markov chain $(X_n)$ with state space $E=\{1,2\}$. If given a transition matrix

$$P=\pmatrix{1-a&a\\b&1-b}\;,$$

with $0<a,b<1$.

How to find out the $n$-th power to the matrix $P$?

Meanwhile, how to find the stationary distribution of the Markov Chain and the mean recurrence time?

Comment: The problem doesn't make sense as it is right now. Do you have more information?

Comment: I assume you need to find an expression for the $n^{th}$ power of the matrix. Have you tried to calculate the first few powers to see if there is a pattern?

Comment: The sum of the rows is always $1$, thus $\left(1, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)$ is an eigenpair of $P$. Trace gives you the other eigenvalue, diagonalize $P$ and you're done. **Edit:** Now that you added the reference to Markov chains, if by any chance you want the limit of the sequence $\left(P^n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, then you might have a theorem that immediately tells you what the limit is without too much trouble.

Comment: @Johanna That's... a huge leap? I guess you could be recognizing it as a commonly asked problem? I guess Kyle will let everybody know either way.

Comment: @Tacet, why would you use this when there is a good deal of methods that can give the result instantly?

Comment: @mvggz There is no point, right. Removed.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Comment: @Did Can he accept an answer with his reputation? I think I recall that I needed at least 100 reputation to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

> The algebraic way: work in the ideal $\langle P\rangle$...

Note that $P=(1-c)I+Q$ where $c=a+b$ and $$Q=\begin{pmatrix}b&a\\ b&a\end{pmatrix},$$ hence $Q^2=cQ$, more generally, $Q^k=c^{k-1}Q$ for every $k\geqslant1$ hence $$P^n=(1-c)^nI+\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}(1-c)^{n-k}Q^k=(1-c)^nI+\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}(1-c)^{n-k}c^{k-1}Q,$$ that is, $P^n=(1-c)^nI+r_nQ$ where $$r_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}(1-c)^{n-k}c^{k-1}=\frac1c\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(1-c)^{n-k}c^{k}-\frac1c(1-c)^n=\frac{1-(1-c)^n}c.$$ Thus, for every $n\geqslant0$,$$P^n=\begin{pmatrix}(1-c)^n+r_nb&r_na\\ r_nb&(1-c)^n+r_na\end{pmatrix},$$ and finally, $$P^n=\frac1{a+b}\begin{pmatrix}b+a(1-a-b)^n&a-a(1-a-b)^n\\ b-b(1-a-b)^n&a+b(1-a-b)^n\end{pmatrix}.$$ *Exercise:* (1) Why is the expression for $P^n$ especially simple when $a+b=1$? (2) What is the limit of $P^n$ when $n\to\infty$, in the general case? (3) Simplify the computations above, (proving and) using the fact that the sums of the rows of $P^n$ are $1$, for every $n$.

Comment: 1) a+b=1 -> P is a matrix of rank one: $P^2 = tr(A)*P$ Hence the very easy form.
2): One has to treat both cases : (1-a-b)<1 , (1-a-b)>1. Converges for the first case, diverges for the other.

Answer (score 3):

The two eigenvalues of your matrix P are: $ p_1 = 1 $, $ p_2 = 1-(a+b) $

Here two things can happen : $ p_1 \neq p_2$ or $p_1 = p_2$. Since $p_1 = p_2\implies a=-b $ and that 0 < a,b , we can eliminate this possibility.

So P has two different eigenvalues, P is a 2x2 square matrix, hence it is diagonalizable in a basis of eigenvectors. One of them can be $ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix} $ for the eigenvalue 1. I'll let you find the other.

When you have found the other vector, if you write the matrix B defined as such: $B = (V_1 V_2)$ where $V_1$ is the eigenvector for 1, $V_2$ the other, you have:

$B^{-1}*P*B = D  = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1-(a+b)}\;$

Now : $ (B^{-1}*P*B)^n = B^{-1}*P^n*B = D^n =  \pmatrix{1&0\\0&(1-(a+b))^n}\; $

You can then get $P^n$ easily.

By the way, one other method would be using lagrange's interpolation. You take the polynomials that respectively have 1 and 1-(a+b) as roots and the value 1 at the other eigenvalue (I'll note them $P_1$ and $P_2$), and write :

$X^n = a_n*P_1(X) +b_n*P_2(X)$ You find the two coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ with the conditions:

$ P_1(1)=0, P_1(1-(a+b))=1; P_2(1)=1, P_2(1-(a+b)) =0 $

Replace everything ang you'll have what you want by evaluating the relation in X=P

Answer (score 1):

Claim:

$$(a+b)P^n=(1-a-b)^n\pmatrix{a&-a\\-b&b}+\pmatrix{b&a\\b&a}$$
Surely true for $n=0$. Assume true for $n=k$.
Then

$$(a+b)P^{k+1}=\pmatrix{1-a&a\\b&1-b}\left ((1-a-b)^k\pmatrix{a&-a\\-b&b}+\pmatrix{b&a\\b&a}\right )$$
$$...algebra...=(1-a-b)^{k+1}\pmatrix{a&-a\\-b&b}+\pmatrix{b&a\\b&a}$$
So true for all n by induction.